# How to restrict an app if it's used outside the defined Google maps position

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an app that I created. The issue now is that I want the app to throw an error if the person is using it outside the defined GPS location. Say for instance I have defined my house as the only location where one can use the app. If the person is using the app maybe 100m away from the house it should notify him that he is out of range.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can ask your coding related problem here but if you expecting to get logics made for you, I am afraid it may not possible here.

Comment: I get it, It's just that I'm a beginner in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use with below ... code..

**first you can save your home latLngBounds using below line.. and save into prefrence**

```
LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
```

after that compare that bounds with your location with below...

```
    if (!bounds.contains(lt2)) {
        //is in not in home location
    }else{
         //is in home location
      }
```

Comment: Chirag, Thanks a lot.

Comment: tick right if you achieve your goal... @lemonadejuice501